# Extending NavigatorFactory to log actions like click(), sendKeys()

Tags: groovy, geb

I'm trying to override few methods like click() and leftShift()/value() to log the action using any logging lib like log4j / slf4j.

Can NavigatorFactory(http://gebish.org/manual/current/#navigator-factory) be used to extend/override methods in EmptyNavigator and NonEmptyNavigator class?

If yes, can you please provide pointer/steps/code snippet that needs to be done to achieve this.

If not possible, please suggest any other way of achieving this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks 
to @erdi (Marcin Erdmann) in geb mailing list, Able to achieve overriding methods in NonEmptyNavigator. Below is the snippet which did the trick for me.

GebConfig.groovy

```
innerNavigatorFactory = { Browser browser, List<WebElement> elements ->
 elements ? new NonEmptyCustomNavigator(browser, elements) : new EmptyCustomNavigator()
}
```

NonEmptyCustomNavigator.groovy

```
import geb.Browser
import geb.navigator.Navigator
import geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

@Log4j
class NonEmptyCustomNavigator extends NonEmptyNavigator{

 NonEmptyCustomNavigator(Browser browser, Collection<? extends WebElement> contextElements) {
 super(browser, contextElements)
 }

 @Override
 Navigator click() {
 ensureContainsSingleElement("click")
 contextElements.first().click()
 log.info("[" + contextElements.first().toString() + "] Click element")
 this
 }
}
```

EmptyCustomNavigator.groovy

```
import geb.Browser
import geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator

class EmptyCustomNavigator extends EmptyNavigator {

 EmptyCustomNavigator(Browser browser) {
 super(browser)
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should give @erdi (Marcin Erdmann), the maintainer of Geb, some credit for answering your question on the Geb mailing list. Here it looks as if you solved the problem all alone.

Comment: @kriegaex - edited answer with credit. Intension of answering was to share knowledge and not to take credit for answer